# Typeclass with constructor functions

Tags: scala, typeclass

What is the preferred way to call functions which constructs instances implementing certain type classes e.g. `deserialize` in the following example:

```
// Simulacrum annotation
@typeclass trait Encodable[A] {
  def deserialize(bytes: Seq[Byte]): Try[A] // Constructor
  def serialize(proof: A): Seq[Byte]
}

// implementation Encodable for Int
implicit val IntEncodable: Encodable[Int] = new Encodable[Int] {
  def deserialize(bytes: Seq[Byte]): Try[Int] = Success(bytes.head)
  def serialize(value: Int): Seq[Byte] = List(value.toByte)
}

// import Simulacrum generated ops
import Encodable.ops._

// is it best practise to define a function like this for all constructor-like functions in the typeclass?
def deserialize[A:Encodable](bytes: Vector[Byte])(implicit instance: Encodable[A]): Try[A] = instance.deserialize(bytes)
// or def deserialize[A:Encodable](bytes: Vector[Byte]): Try[A] = Encodable[A].deserialize(bytes) 

// call constructor
val value: Int = deserialize(Vector(1)).get
// call method
println(value.serialize)
```

Comment: `[A:Encodable]` and `(implicit instance: Encodable[A])` seems redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this is overkill. My preferred way, and what I have seen in other code bases, is just:

```
val value: Int = Encodable[Int].deserialize(Vector(1)).get
```

I don't think much is gained by that additional `deserialize` method. I have also seen:

```
val value: Int = implicitly[Encodable[Int]].deserialize(Vector(1)).get
```

Which might be more familiar to those who haven't seen simulacrum before, but I don't think it's that necessary.